# Deployment with approval environment Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I use an environment attached to a deployment job to manually either rollback or approve a prior deployment.
However, the job after the deployment job gets not executed once I reject the deployment job. Using `not(canceled())` as condition, I would assume the job should run, even if the previous job failed/got rejected. What am I doing wrong? I cannot see anything in Azure´s docs on that.

```
  jobs:
   - deployment: ManualApproval
    displayName: Approve manual oversight gate
    environment: ${{ variables.gateEnvironment }}
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: none
          - checkout: none
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: "Set variable"
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isApproved;isoutput=true]true"
     - deployment: AutomateActions
      displayName: Run conditional steps
      dependsOn: [ManualApproval]
      condition: not(canceled())
      pool:
        name: dpy-pool-dev
      environment: 'AKS'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - download: none
            - checkout: none
            - task: PowerShell@2
              displayName: "Check variable"
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  if ((-not $isApproved)) {
                    throw "trigger failed job condition"
                  }
                  Write-Host "trigger success job condition"
          on:
            success:
              steps:
              - download: none
              - checkout: none
              - ${{ if eq(parameters.stageName, 'ValidateApp') }}:
                - task: PowerShell@2
                  condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
                  displayName: "Delete backup image tag"
                  env:
                    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      # do something
            failure:
              steps:
              - download: none
              - checkout: none
              - task: PowerShell@2
                displayName: "Revert image tag"
                env:
                 AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)
                inputs:
                 targetType: 'inline'
                 script: |
                   # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement anything in the yaml to achieve approval just follow the [approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals) instruction.

1. Remove the whole ManualApproval job.
2. Go to AKS environment in the ADO and add an Approvers (User or Group) in the **Approvals and checks** tab.
3. Remove the dependsOn and condition from the AutomateActions deployment job

```
dependsOn: [ManualApproval]
condition: not(canceled())
```

After that, you should be able to approve or reject deployment to the AKS environment.

Comment: No, I need to run something after it is already deployed, basically post-approval job. I can separate the jobs into stages to make it work, but I thought this is more natively achievable but it feels more like a workaround.